# Is there a undo-close-buffer plugin inside Emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer, undo

Just like that inside firefox we can restore the closed tab (buffer in Emacs case). Seems it should not be too hard to write one, but before reinventing the wheel, is there any good one that people has written, a quick google search did not return a satisfying results.

Comment: Have you already looked at the built-in `desktop.el`?  You do not have to automatically reopen everything when starting Emacs if you don't want to -- this could be an interactive choice you make.  For example, I have a custom version of `desktop.el` and I have the function `desktop-read` on the `emacs-startup-hook` -- I could just as easily remove the hook and manually call `desktop-read` whenever I want.

Comment: I've been using desktop for years, but as I understand, it's all about restoring the session of last time? But when I just closed a buffer and want it back, is there any good way?

Comment: You can use the `kill-buffer-hook` to add the appropriate data to the desktop file.  For example, `desktop.el` uses the `kill-emacs-hook` and you'd also be using the `kill-buffer-hook`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an existing such feature.  But you could code one up, e.g.,  advising `kill-buffer`.

Have a Boolean option analogous to `delete-by-moving-to-trash`. Before killing a buffer, save its relevant information (for re-creating it) for later retrieval. If you want to allow such undo for more than one buffer at a time (e.g. not just for the last one killed), then put the saved info on an alist, etc.

*However*, just what information is needed to **save** and **restore** a given buffer is *not obvious* - it depends on the particular buffer (at least its mode, but even perhaps other parts of its history/state).

So in the general case this is problematic. You can probably come up with something workable and useful for some of your use cases, but just be aware that there is probably no good general answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're describing but the **recentf** package will let you reopen recent files. It's part of Emacs, so there's no package to install. Add this to your init file,

```
(require 'recentf)
(recentf 1)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x R") 'recentf-open-files)
```

and then if you close a file, you can hit C-x R to see a list of recently opened files to choose from.

The list of files is also persisted to `recentf-save-file`.

---

The only problem is it doesn't move the last closed file to the top of the list - if it did you could call `recentf-open-most-recent-file-1` which would open that file, giving you an undo close file function.

It might be a matter of moving the file to the front of the list in this function -

```
(defun recentf-track-closed-file ()
  "Update the recent list when a buffer is killed.
That is, remove a non kept file from the recent list."
  (and buffer-file-name
       (recentf-remove-if-non-kept buffer-file-name)))
```